# How to require and auto load files properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into quite a few errors around how to require files property. Hoping for some insight.

There are files as so:

```
app/models
   model.rb    
app/workers
   parent_worker.rb
   app/workers/directory_1
      directory_worker.rb
      foo_worker.rb
      bar_worker.rb

class DirectoryWorker < ParentWorker
end

class FooWorker < DirectoryWorker
  def method_called_by_model
  end
end
```

When I call the method, method_called_by_model I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Model::FooWorker
```

I've added the following to application.rb, didn't add app/workers since it should be loaded automatically according to the documentation.

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/workers/directory_1"
```

When I require_relative the worker files in the model I get the following error referring to the inherited class being unknown:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant DirectoryWorker
from project/app/workers/directory_1/FooWorker.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any have any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to namespace those workers since they are inside a directory.

First remove the autoload call you added.

Here's how the files should be named and what they should look like inside.

```
# app/workers/parent_worker.rb
class ParentWorker
end

# app/workers/directory_1/directory_worker.rb
class Directory1::DirectoryWorker < ParentWorker
end

# app/workers/directory_1/foo_worker.rb
class Directory1::FooWorker < Directory1::DirectoryWorker
  def method_called_by_model
  end
end

# app/workers/directory_1/bar_worker.rb
class Directory1::BarWorker < Directory1::DirectoryWorker
end
```

Comment: Did as you suggested, though I assume the Directory1:: before ParentWorker was a typo. Getting the error, NameError: uninitialized constant DirectoryWorker::FooWorker.

Comment: Yep that was a typo. Can you post the updated code along with the full error message and the line you get the error on?

Comment: I actually figured it out. Totally my fault, named the files incorrectly DirectoryWorker.rb instead of directory_worker.rb.